# css animation like google's 'Search tools'

Tags: css, angularjs, animate.css

If you click on the 'Search tools' when googling something, it does some animation on the the thingy below it;

I've tried to do the same thing, but I was uncusessfull.
this is my testing plnker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8WdFwWbfHvgpGrzqs5Cb?p=preview

this is my current try on the annimations:

```
/* when hiding the thing */
.ng-hide-add         { 
  -webkit-animation:0.5s lightSpeedOut ease; 
  animation:0.5s lightSpeedOut ease; 
}

/* when showing the thing */
.ng-hide-remove      { 
  -webkit-animation:0.5s flipInX ease; 
  animation:0.5s flipInX ease; 
}

/* ANIMATIONS (FROM ANIMATE.CSS) */

/* flip in */
@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:  rotateX(0deg);
    transform:  rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }


  100% {
    -webkit-transform:  rotateX(90deg);
    transform:  rotateX(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90);
    transform: rotateX(90);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0);
    transform: rotateX(0)
  }
}

/* light speed out */
@-webkit-keyframes lightSpeedOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
    transform: rotateX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes lightSpeedOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) skewX(30deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) skewX(30deg);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) skewX(30deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

anyone that want to give it a try and comes close, a simple share would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I wrote a simple jQuery toggle that does the job. I don't know if you intend for your text options to slide to the right as they do in your example, but checking googles 'Search options' button they switch up and down between the number of results and the search options themselves, so that's what I have created. If you want something different you'll need to describe it in a little more detail!

Anyway, jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rj2w91x2/1/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul id='list-one'>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id='list-two'>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="btn">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 60px;
}
#list-one {
    list-style: none;
}
#list-one li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#list-two {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
#list-two li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $('#list-one').slideToggle();
    $('#list-two').slideToggle();
});
```

You can see the behaviour on the fiddle, just click the 'Toggle' button. Animation is a bit jumpy one way that's I think just a styling issue (barely styled anything for simplicities sake).

This is doable in pure JS/CSS3 but since you're using JS anyway why make things harder?

Comment: It's indeed not with angular, but hey, whatever works :)